# If condition all over the rows in pandas python is not working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to do if condition in pandas dataframe.
I have two conditions:
I have two cols abc and pqr, if df[‘abc’] is null then return df[‘pqr’] else return df[‘abc’]
I have tried the below things:

```
Df[‘mn’]=np.where(pd.isnull(df[‘abc’],df[‘pqr’],df[‘abc’]<br/>
Df[‘mn’]=np.where(df[‘abc’].isna(),df[‘pqr’],df[‘abc’]<br/>

Df[‘mn’]=np.where(df[‘abc’].isnull(),df[‘pqr’],df[‘abc’]
```

Condition 2:To compare two rows

```
Df[‘mn’]=np.where(df[‘abc’]==df['pqr'],df[‘pqr’],df[‘abc’]

Df.loc[df[abc’]==df[‘pqr’],’mn’]=df[‘pqr’]
Df.loc[df[abc’]!=df[‘pqr’],’mn’]=df[‘abc’]
```

I am not getting any error but I am not getting the proper output.

Comment: Sir did your query solved?

Answer (score 0):

Try combining your 1st and 2nd condition together:

```
Df['mn']=np.where((df['abc'].isna()) & (df['abc'].eq(df['pqr'])),df['pqr'],df['abc'])
```

Now if you print `df` you will get your expected output